# Cordova screenshot plugin: doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova 6.4.0 and the plugin com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot 0.1.5 "Screenshot". 
This is my simple code

```
    navigator.screenshot.save(function(error, res)
                          {
                          if(error)
                          {
                          alert(error);
                          }

                          else
                          {
                          alert(res.filePath); //just to see the path

                          }
                          }, 'jpg');
```

The code works on android: the screenshot is taken and saved, so I can use it. However, it doesn't work on iOS: I can't find the screenshot. 
How can I solve?

Comment: Besides, on IOS, the path obtained is: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/some code(25BF5D81-......)/tmp/'screenshotname'.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

To save the image to the photo gallery use this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-save-image-gallery

https://github.com/agomezmoron/cordova-save-image-gallery/blob/master/README.md

Using the plugin and the screenshot plugin to save image.

```
navigator.screenshot.URI(function(error,res){

    if(error){

        console.error(error);

    }else{

        var params = {data: res, prefix: 'myPrefix_', format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};

        window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,  function (filePath) {

          console.log('File saved on ' + filePath);

        },
        function (msg) {

            console.error(msg);

        }

      );

     }
}, 'jpg', 50);
```

**Edit:**

I don't think I understood the question properly.

I don't think you will be able to navigate on iOS to the directory. Instead you will need to get the data as a URI and use something like the camera plugin to store it in the photo library.

That is if you are trying to view the image? I think the plugin is designed to just return you a screenshot and save it in the app's temp directory. It is up to you to either display the image or store it in another location.

**Original Answer**

I think the issue is iOS only uses jpg and doesn't expect the 'jpg' argument. Try changing your code to

```
    navigator.screenshot.save(function(error, res)
                      {
                      if(error)
                      {
                      alert(error);
                      }

                      else
                      {
                      alert(res.filePath); //just to see the path

                      }
                      });
```

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that, when I try to look for the screenshot in the gallery, i can't find it. So, where the application saves the photo on iOS? How can i use that screenshot?

Comment: I have added some information about saving using a plugin.